# Make child element resize when adding new elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent element that has multiple child divs. One, the "content" area, will always be visible and contain a scrollable section of material. My problem is that I can't get it to resize properly based on how many OTHER div elements are included. I could obviously size it manually, but my problem is I have a few dynamic elements that can be added to the parent element that will push the "content" section down.

Is there a way to have the content area resize itself with CSS? Or will I have to use a JS implementation? Here is a basic (without the dynamic element) example of what happens:

[JSFiddle here **Edit**: (updated to include what I want it to look like)](http://jsfiddle.net/yLa6v2qk/6/)

```
<div id="mytest"> 
    Test
    <div id="topper">
           Other Test
    </div>
    <div id="rollit">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit:
My problem is that I don't want "rollit" to expand the parent div, I want "rollit" to readjust itself to fit. This part is key since the "topper" piece in my code is actually added dynamically. In short, the "mytest" div should remain the same size regardless, the topper div is added later, which SHOULD (does not currently) shrink "rollit" so that "rollit" still fits within the parent div.

Comment: If you get rid of the `height` in your CSS for your `mytest` div it will adjust the height "dynamically"...

Comment: What do you mean by the content div `resizing properly` / `resizing itself`?

Comment: Use percentages for the width property in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to `mytest`:

```
display: table;
```

Add two `div`s to `mytest`, with these classes:

```
.row1 {
  display: table-row;
  height: 0px;
}

.row2 {
  display: table-row;
}
```

`row2` will contain the content you want to fit (`rollit`).  `row1` will contain the rest of the content.

Because you're setting a height on `mytest`, its rows will try to expand proportionally to fit that height.  `height: 0px` causes `row1` to take up only as much height as is needed for its content.

The `overflow` style on `rollit` prevents `row2` from growing beyond the bounds of `mytest`.

**Snippet:**

```css
#mytest {
  display: table;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: yellow;
}

.row1 {
  display: table-row;
  height: 0px;
}

.row2 {
  display: table-row;
}

#topper {
  height: 30px; 
}

#rollit {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto; 
}
```

```html
<div id="mytest">
  <div class="row1">
    Test
    <div id="topper">
      Other Test
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <div class="row2">
    <div id="rollit">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do all additional DIVs have to have the table-row property for this to work? EDIT: Just tested, it doesn't appear so.

Comment: No, my answer assumes that you want only one element to fit, so it's the only one that should go in `row2`.  Everything else can go in `row1`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
#mytest {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#topper {
    height: 30px;
}
#rollit {
    width: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
    height:200px;
}
```

basically, do not set a `height` to an element you want to auto-expand..

http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/yLa6v2qk/5/

Comment: My problem is that I don't want it to expand the parent div, I want the smaller one to readjust itself to fit.

Comment: I've added an example to show what I want it to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/yLa6v2qk/6/

Comment: @Organiccat you can use [CSS Flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) on modern browsers. Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/yLa6v2qk/7/